# Mongoose remove a entire object from a nested array

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using mongoose 4.11.3. I'm trying to remove a object from a nested array.
This is my schema

```
var VendorSchema = new Schema({
  _id: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "User"
    },

  services: [{    
              _id:false,
              service_category: {

                          type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                          ref: "ServiceCategory"
                    },
              sub_services :[{
              _id:false,
              service : {
                          type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                          ref: "Service"
                        },
              service_description:{
                         type: String,
                         default: null
              }
              }]                      
    }]
});
```

And I need to remove objects in sub_services array. So this is what I have done

```
Vendor.update({'services.service_category': req.body.category_id}, {$pull :{'services.$.sub_services': { "service": req.body.service_id }}},function(err,obj){
            if(err){ 
                return res.json({success: false, msg: err});
            }
            else{    
                return res.json({success: true, msg:"removed" });
            }    
});
```

Above code is executing without any errors.But after removing, the entire object has not been removed

```
{
    "_id": "598b28271a0b551af8fbf849",
    "services": [
        {
            "service_category": {
                "_id": "598b27f21a0b551af8fbf848",
                "category_name": "Venue"
            },
            "sub_services": [
                {
                    "service": {
                        "_id": "598b29611a0b551af8fbf84a",
                        "service": "Conference hall"
                    },
                    "service_description": "This is test description for a service"
                },
                {
                    "service": {
                        "_id": "598c66f5003db00aec18696e",
                        "service": "Auditorium"
                    },
                    "service_description": "This is test description for a service auditorium"
                },
                {
                    "service_description": null
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Some properties are remaining with null values after the removal. But I want to remove the entire object by a objectID (service ref).
Can anyone help me on this

Comment: Not from that code using `$pull`. If I replicate your schema I can remove the entire `sub_services` entry as would be expected of `$pull`. If you have an item left with a `null` description then that happened as a result of another update attempt. Likely using `$unset` instead. The `$pull` operator removes the entire element from the array that matches the supplied condition.